# How to avoid getting duplicate posts from database in an "infinite scrolling" system?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

I have an AJAX system that fetch posts from database and then create DIVs in my layout to put them. When te user reachs the end of the page then many other posts will be loaded by the API. The problem is, how can I get the following 10 posts that are just the previously posts of the last that is already loaded? The same thing I want to happen when I load the new posts at the top, how to show every post in the right order without missing any post or duplicating any post?

Sorry for the bad explanation and the bad english.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to store the id of the last retrieved message.  When you submit the new request, send the last received message id and have php/mysql return the results from there.

---

If your query looks something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE username='redcurley' LIMIT 10
```

Then you'd need to modify to be something more like:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE username='redcurley' AND id > :id LIMIT 10
```

You could alternatively use the offset method that Scott mentions.

---

**Edit:** I assumed you were using auto-increment ids because it's so common. Since you aren't, you need some way to keep track of the last message returned.  You can do this through sorting the records in a way that they'll come out in the same order every time and use offsets.

Comment: Definitely how I'd do it. And this is assuming that the OP is ordering the results in the query in some way (such as date/time), so that this scheme can be used.

Comment: That is the correct way to do that, but you should also add one important notice: **this requires IDs to be auto-incremented** (like `auto increment` in MySQL), so they always rise for every new post. This will not work eg. for IDs being like UUID.

Comment: @Tadeck Not exactly. As long as the results are ordered in some way, there's no reason you can't use something like `id`

Comment: @Ian: This is exactly what I meant: to use your solution, the IDs need to be _monotonic_ (eg. rising with every new entry). This is easiest to achieve by using auto-incremented columns, but there are of course other solutions (like Unix timestamp, if you will be sure there is no more than one entry for specific timestamp, or like primary key from some kind of log table having auto-incremented IDs). Without ensuring IDs will always keep the order I mentioned, this solution will fail.

Comment: So in this case I MUST use auto-incremented IDs? I usually use random/unique IDs. It wouldn't work?

Comment: @RedCurley You just need some way to reliably sort the messages and keep track of the value of the last-returned row.

Comment: @RedCurley: The IDs need to maintain the order of the time the posts were created (because you are sorting the entries based on creation time). You can use some kind of randomness, or obfuscate it (eg. base64 encode IDs, so the user is not able to see them), or add more complex solution (like referring to "ends" of currently displayed list using these non-monotonic IDs, and reading their creation time on the server just before invoking query mentioned in this answer), but to use this query you still need monotonic IDs, so yes (although not necessarily auto-incremented).

Comment: @Tadeck Using the new edit from Levi, yes it will fail unless you use auto-incremented IDs. I guess what I meant was that say the query was using `ORDER BY date_recorded` or something. If you know the "last" `id`, then you can get everything after it in the result set (whatever that SQL would be) and doesn't require a number for an ID.

Comment: @Ian: Yes, I agree about the "no need for a number" part. But whatever you will pick, it will need to maintain the order and be unique (date/timestamp is not really a good example here, as it does not guarantee uniqueness, unless used with something additional). You can as well use some other column as a pointer to the eg. latest news displayed on the page, then pull it from database, read its ID and use it for condition like this answer suggests. This will hide the auto-incremented ID from the end user, but this will actually do what I mentioned already.

Comment: Well, if I start using ordened integers and if I have post number `64` and I want to store this number in an integer with size 10 in the database how should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use an OFFSET in your query, which would work even if you wanted to get results that may have out-of-order IDs.  So if you had -

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE username='foo' LIMIT 10
```

The next query would be

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE username='foo' LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

and so on like that as you fetch more and more records.  Your Javascript would have to keep track of the offset and send it to the server with the AJAX request.

Comment: Or maybe keep track of the number of "pages" and use `OFFSET 10 * pages` where `pages` is a parameter in whatever way, either way this is the right implementation in the query! You could just always use this kind of clause `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10 * pages` so the first time, `pages` would have a value of `0` and would end up having an OFFSET of 0 (which is default, I think)

Comment: The problem is the following, what if there are new posts meanwhile the user is navigating?

Comment: That will stop working for one of the cases OP mentioned, as you would need to load _both_ older (but not yet shown) and newer entries (created since last page load). So basically because the size of the result will grow, you will probably have duplicates.

Comment: I want something like Twitter does. Don't miss any result and don't load any duplicate entry.

Comment: Thats a good point.  But assuming you're ordering your query by ID or a date entered or something like that (and if you want results in order, you should be letting the database do it for you), either will work, because new posts will still end up at the end of the result set, and so will fall in the correct place with the OFFSET.  Either way, you need to order your result set and select rows in chunks, and both solutions accomplish this. But considering implementation, selecting based on ID is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

To allow near infinate results you can't use an AUTO_INCREMENT as there is eventually a limit.

What you can do though is when posted add a timestamp to the row and then in first load there is no timestamp given to the AJAX handle code so it gets them all and sends back the timestamp the query was run at then when it recives it it can then use a different query that has `WHERE timestamp > $sentTimestamp`

E.G

```
<?php
// AJAX handler code
$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM posts"

if(!empty($_REQUEST['lastPull'])){
    $sqlQuery .= " WHERE `timestamp` > ".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['lastPull']);
}
// do your query and formatting for AJAX response here
?>
```

Comment: Timestamps are not unique.  Also, could you please stop using `mysql_*` functions? The use of the extension is discouraged.

Comment: Just as another when your only query point is a single row use INDEX this will then perform at about the same rate as an AUTO_INCREMENT lookup

Comment: They don't need to be unique that's the point unique is if you ever need to pull out a single row for what the OP is asking that will never happen and the `mysql_*` function is only to show that there should be some escaping done that is not an Exact code he should use its and Example thats the point of E.G "to give an example of a specific instance"

Answer (score 0):

When user load page, You can fetch all last 10 post with page load,

for example -

id      POST
1       Post1
2       Post2
3       Post3
.
.
.
10     Post10

So when user scroll page bottom, You will call your ajax code and pass you last id as input and make paggination using LIMIT in your SQL query.

For example -
My last post id is 50 and user scroll down page, So query will fire,
Select * from tableName where id < 50 LIMIT 10

This is for old post, and mean while if any new post then you can check new post using new query with last id at the time of user refresh page.
Select * from tableName where id > 50 LIMIT 10

This is for new post, return both collection in single request to page and by evaluating both you can inserts new div tag to show this.

You can use ajax and JSON combination, [Click Here](http://mycodeprograms.blogspot.in/p/json.html) if you want more deail about JSON and AJAX.