# Paginating in MySQL without duplicate results across different pages

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

On our web app we have pages that query user posts, with pagination. We are sorting our posts by a user-generated ranking (like reddit) that is subject to change as a user may be paging through the posts. We are trying to prevent a post that has already been shown to be selected again. Is there a way to go about this? For example Facebook manages to do it in some way, where new posts don't mess with the actual query you're scrolling through.

Some of the things I'm thinking could solve the problem, but I'm not sure are even doable:

1. "snapshot" the ranking table when a user is on the first page and simply keep querying later pages from this snapshot. That way the order won't change, but not sure if its possible to do anything like this.
2. Query a big amount, for example 500 posts at once, and simply traverse through that result. This could work for a user since its unthinkable that a user would ever go through more than 500 posts at once. This is probably very inefficient though. If you where to do this,however , it would be pretty simple to then `memcache` the result for, say 10 minutes, and simply get the posts from the result you stored in memcache (10 minute delay in updated data shouldn't bother anyone), which in turn is very efficient, since most users will load posts without even querying the db. Of course for pages where I order by posts by newest, I couldn't use this caching method, but there it's easier to put a provision in place to avoid duplicates [as detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478901/how-to-avoid-getting-duplicate-posts-from-database-in-an-infinite-scrolling-sy).

3) Going off the `memcache` idea, I could of course `memcache` in smaller bits (say 20 posts at a time) but that could very well still lead to duplicate posts.

This is more or less the current code we are using to get posts on a page:

```
     $page = $_GET['page']; //getting the page number
     if(empty($page)){$page = 1;}
     $per_page = 5; //number of posts per page
     $pcount = $page*$per_page;
     $start_p = ($pcount - $per_page); //offset for sql query

     $query = "SELECT p.*
        FROM posts as p
        INNER JOIN post_rankings as r ON p.ID = r.post_id
        ORDER BY r.ranking DESC
        LIMIT $per_page OFFSET $start_p";
```

This code works fine for properly getting the right posts, but of course it does not account for possible movements in the order, hence giving us duplicate posts. Any ideas?